# React.js useState with Array.push method on functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to change value of state with `useState` hook, but I've never worked with `useState` hook in functional component before, and I get a very strange error. Even though I define all of my variables as `string[]`, it tries to define whole array as `number`.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { NextPage } from 'next'

const IndexPage: NextPage = () => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = React.useState<string[]>([])

  return (
    <>
      {
        ["Dallas", "Oregon", "New York", "California"].map((x: string) =>
          <button onClick={() => setCountries(countries.push(x))}>
            <span>{x}</span>                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          </button>
        )
      }
    <>
  )
}
```

Here is strange error I get:

```js
(method) Array<string>.push(...items: string[]): number
"Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<string[]>'.ts(2345)"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Array.push returns a number so you have to change your code to this

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { NextPage } from 'next'

const IndexPage: NextPage = () => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = React.useState<string[]>([])

  return (
    <>
      {
        ["Dallas", "Oregon", "New York", "California"].map((x: string) =>
          <button onClick={() => {
          // either this
          setCountries(countries.concat(x))
          // or
          setCountries([...countries, x]
          }>
            <span>{x}</span>                  
          </button>
        )
      }
    <>
  )
}
```

Comment: If any of those 2 ways does not work, try using `setCountries(countries => ([...countries, x]))`. It worked for me this way.

Comment: @PedroLuz This worked out fantastic! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you need to pass an array of strings to `setCountries`

```
<button onClick={() => setCountries([...countries, x])}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.push returns number :

> The new length property of the object upon which the method was
>   called.

Also you probably don't want to mutate the state, try `setCountries(countries.concat(x))`

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `setCountries` expects that you pass an array of string items, but what is being passed to it is the return type of the function `Array.push` which is of type `number`

If you want to just remove a country on clicking that button, you can do so using -

```
return (
    <>
      {
        ["Dallas", "Oregon", "New York", "California"].map((x: string) =>
          <button onClick={() => setCountries(countries.concat(x))}>
            <span>{x}</span>                  
          </button>
        )
      }
    <>
  )
```